# How can I move an 8-bit number to address 00FEh?

Tags: assembly, x86-16, tasm

I'm studying 8086 assembly and I have this question:

> Move the content of BL (an 8-bit number) to the address 00FEh. Use base addressing with a displacement offset.

I made this:

```
MOV 00FEh,BL
```

but TASM gives an error.

> esempio1.asm(16) illegal immediate
>   Error messages: 1 Warning messages: none

I would like solution and little explication.

Comment: Say it in your mother tongue and let google, or a bilingual user, to do the translation for that expression, if you can't.

Comment: "Base addressing" is fine, btw. I can't understand what "crowding out" means in this context.

Comment: i try to search translation. one more time

Comment: You should [edit] your post to include the error that tasm generates as well.

Comment: Tasm probably expects `MOV [00FEh],BL` or `MOV byte [00FEh],BL` or `MOV byte ptr [00FEh],BL`

Comment: sorry i failed to translate 'crowding out' , maybe 'offset'

Comment: I believe with _tasm_ if you just use a displacement value like _00feh_ you are required to specify the segment explicitly. So something like: `MOV DS:00FEh,BL` _DS_ could be any of the segments like _DS_,_ES_,_SS_. Without seeing the rest of your code it would be hard to tell what segment you should be using.

Comment: If your intent is to access physical memory address _0h:00FEh_ then you would have to load a segment register (like _ES_) with the value 0 and then do `MOV ES:00FEh,BL` . You could use _DS_ as well for this. Not sure this was what you even intended because in real mode the first 1024 of memory is the interrupt vector table. Without seeing more of your code it is hard to tell.

Comment: `xor di,di` `mov ds,di` `cli` `mov [di+0FEh],bl` `sti` The brackets contains: [base register + displacement offset]